# AASM state machine exception handling example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine, aasm

I'm currently working on a class, which is basically doing following:

- model gets created
- fetches data (event "get_things!")

  - if exception happens, state should become "failed"
  - if success, state should be "finished"

I try to implement it as following:

```
class Fetcher < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :created, initial: true
    state :success, :failed

    event :succeed do
      transitions from: :created, to: :success
    end

    event :fail do
      transitions from: :created, to: :failed
    end
  end

  def read_things!(throw_exception = false)
    begin
      raise RuntimeError.new("RAISED EXCEPTION") if throw_exception
      self.content = open("https://example.com?asd=324").read
      self.succeed!
    rescue => e
      self.fail!
    end
  end
end

a = Fetcher.new
a.read_things!(throw_exception = true)
=> state should be failed

a = Fetcher.new
a.read_things!(throw_exception = false)
=> state should be succeess
```

It works, but looks somehow not really good to do...

I would prefer something like the error handling which is mentioned in the readme

```
event :read_things do
  before do
    self.content = open("https://example.com?asd=324").read
    self.succeed!
  end
  error do |e|
    self.fail!
  end
  transitions :from => :created, :to => :success
end
```

but I dont know if this is really the best practice here?

I also have many events, which all should behave like my mentioned error handling is showing above and I saw that I can somehow use error_on_all_events - but didnt find any documentation about it?

Any thoughts? Thanks!

*edit:* Changed some small parts to remove confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is the method name `fetch!` or `read_things`? In any case, you don't want to pass a boolean argument to determine whether or not to raise an exception. If an exception is raised then your `rescue` will pick it up:

```
def read_things
  self.content = open("https://example.com?asd=324").read
  succeed!
rescue => e
  # do something with the error (e.g. log it), otherwise remove the "=> e"
  fail!
end
```

> I would prefer something like the error handling which is mentioned in the readme

Your error handling example is actually good practice (with a few minor edits):

```
event :read_things do
  before do
    self.content = open("https://example.com?asd=324").read
  end
  error do |e|
    fail! # the self is optional (since self is your Fetcher object)
  end
  transitions from: :created, to: :success
end
```

In practice:

```
a = Fetcher.new
a.read_things!
```

If `self.content` doesn't raise an exception then the state will transition from `created` to `success` (no need to call `succeed!` directly), otherwise the error handler will call the `fail!` transition, which will attempt to transition the state to `failed`.

**EDIT:**

Example usage of `error_on_all_events` callback with `AASM`:

```
aasm do
  error_on_all_events :handle_error_for_all_events

  state :created, initial: true
  state :success, :failed

  event :succeed do
    transitions from: :created, to: :success
  end

  event :fail do
    transitions from: :created, to: :failed
  end
end

def handle_error_for_all_events
  # inspect the aasm object and handle error...
  puts aasm
end
```

Comment: Thanks, great to hear that I'm not completely wrong. I cleared also some parts in my question, sorry for the confusion! Could you also show me an example of how to use error_on_all_events? thank you very much! The parameter thow_exception was only for demonstration purposes.. :)

Comment: You're welcome! `error_on_all_events` works like any other callback in `aasm`. You can just define the `error_on_all_events` block inside your `aasm` block (answer updated with example).